# Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating custom View class SlidingTabLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, runtime-error

In our project, we changed some API calls, so I had to change some of the objects and change the Splash screen calls but MainActivity and Custom Views remained intact and I did not change them for a longer period of time, but suddenly some errors happen when I call finish() on my SplashScreen and try to start MainActivitiy.

**Here is the Logcat output for my error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sconnected.nkmaribor/pribozic.sconnected.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at pribozic.sconnected.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at pribozic.sconnected.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabStrip
        at pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabLayout.<init>(SlidingTabLayout.java:109)
        at pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabLayout.<init>(SlidingTabLayout.java:96)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at pribozic.sconnected.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is my MainActivity.clas (line 65 is setContentView(R.layout.main))**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    @InjectView(R.id.view_pager) ViewPager viewPager;
    @InjectView(R.id.container) FrameLayout container;
    @InjectView(R.id.sliding_tabs) SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
    @InjectView(R.id.toolbar_actionbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    PublisherInterstitialAd mPublisherInterstitialAd;
    static Context context;
    boolean isLoaded = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        context = this;

        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet)){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), toolbar);
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        }

        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.notificationsCount = 8;
        MyPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.indicator));

        slidingTabLayout.updateNotificationCount(155);

        isLoaded = true;
    }
```

**This is the main.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="pribozic.sconnected.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

I don't know if this is any relative but my SlidingTabLayout view worked great until yesterday and nothing has been changed except some custom objects I have created and new RestClient Service which I've added for the new API calls.

I can provide SlidingTabLayout code but that's a lot of code. The line which says something is wrong is the constructor and where I create SlidingTabStrip. Maybe it has something to do with context? But the view should be created in XML, how can I change context?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you didn't get the answer already!

Its because you are trying to inflate the SlidingTabLayout.java view without defining in main.xml

Possible fixes:

> Check if you have **SlidingTabLayout.java** in **pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabLayout.java** folder.

and then

> Specify SlidingTabLayout in main.xml.

```
<pribozic.sconnected.views.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Hope it helps